# SQL group by returns just first row

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I have a table which contains two columns 'id' and 'layout plan'

I need to see all those rows which have the same layout plan

I use this query.

```
select * 
from project_layout 
group by layout_plan 
having count(layout_plan) > 1
```

But this query is only returning the first row.

I want to see all the groups with the same layout plan.

Comment: may be you have one record in each group plan, so your clause `count(layout_plan) > 1` filters the other records and you see only on record whose count(layout_plan) is more than 1

Answer (score 9):

Databases other than MySQL would give an error if you use a column that's not grouped without an aggregate.  But MySQL will return an indeterminate value from among the group's rows.

To retrieve all the rows in `layout_plan` groups with more than one row, you could use:

```
select  *
from    project_layout
where   layout_plan in
        (
        select  layout_plan 
        from    project_layout 
        group by 
               layout_plan 
        having 
               count(*) > 1
        )
```

Comment: . . MySQL is explicitly documented to return a values from an *indeterminate* row, not the first row (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).  I imagine that you know this, but this answer is being referenced somewhere else.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, "the first value it encounters" is indeterminate. I'll update the answer to be clearer.

Comment: . . Now I understand the original way you wrote it.  Subtly correct, but unfortunately easily misinterpreted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
select * from project_layout 
where layout_plan in (select layout_plan   
            from project_layout    
            group by layout_plan   
            having count(layout_plan) > 1)
```

Comment: Groups for `(id)` tend to all have `count(*) = 1`

Comment: @Andomar Youzah! What a noob I am :/ Edited answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select  a.*
from    project_layout
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            select  layout_plan 
            from    project_layout 
            group   by  layout_plan 
            having  count(layout_plan ) > 1
        ) b ON a.layout_plan = b.layout_plan
```

for faster performance, add an `index` on column `layout_plan`