# SQL "group by" returns just first row - bis

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I understand from this: [SQL group by returns just first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769929/sql-group-by-returns-just-first-row) that MySQL returns only the first value found for a  group.

To simplify I have the following tables:

```
Products
----------------
id | description
----------------
1  | Product-1
2  | Product-2
3  | Product-3


Groups
------
id | description
----------------
1  | Group-1
2  | Group-2


nxm_Products_Groups
---------------------
product_id | group_id | qty
---------------------
1          |   1      | 10
1          |   2      | 10
2          |   1      | 10
3          |   1      | 10
```

Last table is an associative table many-to-many between products and groups.

I want to group by the products, summing up their quantity (`qty`), and when all the products summed are in a single group, I want the group name selected, otherwise I want "??" returned.

MySQL always returns the first group it finds:

```
SELECT  
    G.id AS GROUP_ID,
    G.description,  
    P.id AS PRODUCT_ID,  
    P.description,  
    SUM(GP.qty) AS QTY 
 FROM  
    Groups G  
 JOIN nxm_Products_Groups GP ON (G.id = GP.group_id)  
 JOIN Products P ON (P.id = GP.product_id)  
 GROUP BY P.id  
 ORDER BY GP.group_id;
```

I get:

```
GROUP_ID|description|PRODUCT_ID|description|QTY
1       |Group 1    |2         |Product-2  |10
1       |Group 1    |3         |Product-3  |10
1       |Group 1    |1         |Product-1  |20
```

Edit: maybe my question was not clear. Instead of what I get, I want:

```
GROUP_ID|description|PRODUCT_ID|description|QTY
1       |Group 1    |2         |Product-2  |10
1       |Group 1    |3         |Product-3  |10
???     |???        |1         |Product-1  |20
```

How?

Comment: No real sense? The general GROUP BY rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect.  MySQL is explicitly documented to return a values from an indeterminate row, not the first row (dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: @jarlh Exactly, which is not the case! My query should give an error...

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok thanks, but that's not the point of the question.

Comment: do you not know how to get what you want? or are you just asking why the result is not what you expect?

Comment: is there a reason why you still want to see group_id 1 in the first column, but you dont want to see the description for group_id 1 in the second column?

Comment: @JamieD77 Sorry it is an error, I'll edit the question. I don't know how to get the ??? when the group is a mix of groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `???` instead of `group_ID` since it's an INT field. You can use for example `0`. Try to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT  
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=1 THEN G.id ELSE 0 END AS GROUP_ID,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*)=1 THEN G.description ELSE '\?\?' END AS GROUP_DESC,  
    P.id AS PRODUCT_ID,  
    P.description,  
    SUM(GP.qty) AS QTY 
 FROM  
    Groups G  
 JOIN nxm_Products_Groups GP ON (G.id = GP.group_id)  
 JOIN Products P ON (P.id = GP.product_id)  
 GROUP BY P.id  
 ORDER BY GROUP_ID;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e94ce/12)</kbd>

Comment: Yes but in this case this field `GROUP_ID` will be converted into VARCHAR automatically in a result set